# Read folder of .xls files to a .csv file add blanks lines and converts int to float

Tags: python, excel, csv

Currently my program can open and read all .xlsx files in a folder. It can then write them one by one to a .csv file. HOwever, it adds a blank line after each row and it converts Int to Float which I do not want. Pretty much a newbie.

```
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()
path = tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory(parent=root,title='Select the directory with the assignments to grade')
folder = os.listdir(path)
with open('csvConsolidatedFile.csv', 'wb', delimiter=' ', lineterminator='\n') as outfile:
    wr = csv.writer(outfile)

for xlsFile in folder:
    document = os.path.join(path, xlsFile)
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(document)
    for index in range(1,2):
        sh = wb.sheet_by_name('Sheet' + str(index))
        for rownum in range(sh.nrows):
            wr.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum))

csvConsolidatedFile.close()
```

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?  Also, are all of the `.xlsx` files in the same format?

Comment: Python 3.7 and yes all .xlsx are in the same format.  However, I switched to using pandas and found it all worked well. Not sure if if is faster though.

Comment: The reason for your blank lines is your code is compatible with Python 2.x. You would need `open('abc.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:`